# Struts Cannot find ActionMappings or ActionFormBeans collection

Tags: java, struts

I'm using struts 1.1 and for a while now, I have facing this issue:

Description:

> The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from
>   fulfilling this request.

Exception:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find ActionMappings or ActionFormBeans collection
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:846)
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:779)
>       org.apache.jsp.jspUsuario.registrarUsuario_jsp._jspService(registrarUsuario_jsp.java:150)
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:94)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:324)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)

Root cause:

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find ActionMappings or ActionFormBeans collection
>       org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.lookup(FormTag.java:711)
>       org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:419)
>       org.apache.jsp.jspUsuario.registrarUsuario_jsp._jspx_meth_htm_form_0(registrarUsuario_jsp.java:166)
>       org.apache.jsp.jspUsuario.registrarUsuario_jsp._jspService(registrarUsuario_jsp.java:140)
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:94)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:324)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)

And now when I try to open the page with an action instead of accessing the jsp page directly I get the error: "HTTP Status 404 - Servlet action is not available"

Message:

> Servlet action is not available

Description:

> The requested resource (Servlet action is not available) is not
>   available.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Jason</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

struts-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.1//EN"
    "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_0.dtd">
<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="FormRegistro" type="com.jason.struts.form.UsuarioRegistrarForm"/>
    </form-beans>
    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/RegistrarUsuarioPage" type="com.jason.struts.action.RedirecionarAction">
            <forward name="success" path="/jspUsuario/registrarUsuario.jsp" />
        </action>
        <action input="jspUsuario/registrarUsuario.jsp" name="RegistrarUsuario" path="/registroUsuario" scope="request" validate="false" type="com.jason.struts.action.UsuarioRegistrarAction">
            <forward name="success" path="/WEB-INF/resultado/registroSucesso.jsp" />
            <forward name="reativado" path="/WEB-INF/resultado/registroReativado.jsp" />
        </action>
    </action-mappings>
</struts-config>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Index</title>
    <style>
        <%@ include file="/estilo/folha.css"%>
    </style>
</head>
<body>  
    <div align="center">
        <h2>Bem Vindo!</h2>
        <button type="button" class="botao" id="botaoRegistrarUsuarios" 
            OnClick="parent.location.href='RegistrarUsuarioPage.do'">
            Registrar Usuários </button> <br>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The page I try to open when the error happens:
registrarUsuario.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="htm" %>
<%@ page import = "org.apache.struts.taglib.*,
                   org.apache.struts.*,
                   javax.servlet.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Registrar Usuário</title>
    <style>
        <%@ include file="../estilo/folha.css"%>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <htm:form action = "registroUsuario">
        <htm:submit value="Reg"></htm:submit>
    </htm:form>
</body>
</html>
```

However other pages works just fine. If any other info is needed, please request.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And if it's not the typo, are you accessing a JSP page directly, that uses Struts tags, without going through an action?

Comment: Do i need to use an action to access the page just because it uses Struts tags?

Comment: I'll edit the code with a new Action that links to the JSP page

Comment: Yes, you do; most (all?) of the tags rely on having an action context.

Comment: Ok, i updated and now I have other error. Could you, please, check?

Comment: New question, open a new question. Looks like a startup error.

Comment: Ok. I just checked the console and an odd error appeared. I'll try to fix it.
Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

The cause may be a typo:

- registroUsuario.jsp
- registrarUsuario.jsp

> `<action input="jspUsuario/registroUsuario.jsp" name="RegistrarUsuario" path="/registroUsuario" scope="request" validate="false" type="com.jason.struts.action.UsuarioRegistrarAction">`

---

> The page I try to open when the error happens: registrarUsuario.jsp